# Sync Services and iOS

Tags: iphone, macos, syncservices, mobileme

Suppose I already have an OS X app which syncs its data using [Sync Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SyncServices/Articles/SyncOverview.html) with MobileMe.  Is there an way to make my iPhone/iPad app to sync (using MobileMe or not) the data using what I already prepared for the Sync Services?

I guess Apple already has the implementation inside iOS because iPhone/iPad does sync Safari bookmarks, but it doesn't seem to be available in the SDK...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sync Services is not supported on iOS at the moment, so there is no way to access that synchronization data from iOS devices at the moment.

This is unfortunate because Sync Services would relieve application developers from coming up with homegrown data synchronization solutions. Hopefully Apple will bring Sync Services to iOS in the future.

Comment: Hopefully they'll come up with a comprehensive framework to share data between iOS and OS X...